# 5 sided dice like layout in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm currently working on an Android app and I would like to make a nice layout.
What I'm trying to achieve is the following layout:

[image: layout example]

The circles will be of equal size ofcourse. Besides that i need to be able to click them so they need to be buttons or imageviews.

What would be the best approach to achieve this kind of layout?

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout and ImageViews/ImageButtons.

Comment: Allright that sounds easy enough, will look into it!

Comment: A `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` or `GridLayout` should all do. The latter two might be more suitable if you need the layout to dynamically scale on different screen sizes/ratios (as long as there are no overlapping elements required and the circles are more or less distributed evenly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:gravity="center"
 >

            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                /> 

            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                /> 

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center"
>
            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                /> 


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center"
>

            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                /> 

            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                /> 

 </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This looks very nice indeed. I will accept this answer as it's the closest to the comment Michael Z. made (wich is the real solution).

Comment: @jHogen thanks for accepting.Sean O'Toole has also given good answer indeed.

Comment: Yeah both are decent solutions depending on your specific needs, the RelativeLayout gives you more control of where exactly the dots appear, but I usually find a LinearLayout with weights is better for scaling across different screens. Either way

Comment: @Sean O'Toole yup i hold with you it depends on requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `RelativeLayout`, and say where each of the dots is supposed to be in relation to each of the others.

You could also use a `LinearLayout`, creating three 'rows' of buttons, the top and bottom rows containing two of the 'dots' and the middle one containing one in the center.

The layout would look something like this:

[image: Dice Layout]

And the code would be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/dot2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/dot3"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/dot4"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/dot5"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does seem like an easy way to achieve the layout. Allthough I think the relative layout is easier because I can just place the buttons in each corner and in the center of the screen. But it's still a good answer that might be a better solution for others.

Comment: Yeah it depends on your specific needs, RelativeLayouts give you more control over some of the finer details, though I usually find weighted LinearLayouts to play nicer when scaling over different screens without the need to specify a new layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use a nest of LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. To use the images as button, then use ImageView and indicate in the xml corresponding ID for each image so you can use it in your activity.